# How to make panorama start-up animation like default windows phone panorama app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just wondering how to make panorama start-up animation like music+video or picture app. Notice the sliding 3d animation when we open music+video/picture/marketplace app.

When I create panorama project using VS 2010 Express, the animation is just from right to left.

How do i make that animation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - take a look to [Wp7 silverlight toolkit - page transitions](http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/11/09/Page-Transition-Animations-and-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

Comment: I noticed this too.But animations in silverlight toolkit is not the same as default wp panorama animation.

Comment: You can create such animation in Expression Blend via Transform section of your control (Page).

Comment: Well, i tried that too. And my result are crappier than wp default animation. Is there any guideline how to mimic the animation ? What transformation should i make ?

Answer (score 0):

The animations are there, but if you have too many things running on the UI thread, the animation will be hard to see since loading will be choppy. To test this, just make a new page with a default panorama inside it and observe the animation while its empty. Zune app will always be faster, its run on native code from my understanding.

Comment: The animation is there but it is different animation. Default panorama animation is just simple right to left animation. And Music+Video app animation is 3d animation.